# Sparse implementation of SLSQP

Tags: sparse-matrix, numeric, nonlinear-optimization

I have a nonlinear optimization problem for ~300 variables and 20,000 constraints, where every gradient vector of the constraints has at most 5 nonzero entries. A very sparse system, which I have to solve millions of times (for random initial values). The SLSQP algorithm from the NLopt library works fine, but slowly. Is there an implementation of SLSQP, which can take advantage of the sparsity, and works faster?

I tried the Active Set Method to reduce the number of inequality constraints. That reduced the running time 30 fold. I'd like another 30 fold speedup, without rewritng the SLSQP algorithm myself.

Comment: IMHO it is better to try a proper large sparse solver such as IPOPT. And just to be sure: make sure to provide gradients yourself (or use an automatic differentiation tool).

Comment: I tried to install Ipopt in Windows 10 / msys2. After 3 full days of struggling with error messages of the necessary components, and searching for answers, I gave up. Maybe WSL with Ubuntu 20.04 works? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: There maybe pre built libraries available. Otherwise, you may want to consider to use Knitro (commercial). I use ipopt using gams so I don't have to worry about compiling things (and I get automatic differentiation). You just confirmed that this is a time saver.